# Пишу расширение chrome как добавить кнопку

Tags: javascript, google-extensions

У меня стоит задача написать расширение которое будет добовлять кнопку на странице резюме сайта hh.ru
Пробовал добавить кнопку на stackoverflow, пример:

```js
const asideCta = document.querySelector('.aside-cta');
if (asideCta) {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '#'; 
    link.innerText = 'Моя ссылка'; 

    link.classList.add('ws-nowrap', 's-btn', 's-btn__primary');

    asideCta.appendChild(link);
}
```

Все прекрасно работает, но на сайте hh.ru код

```js
const blockButton = document.querySelector('.bloko-button-group');
if (blockButton) {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerText = 'Моя кнопка'; 

    button.classList.add('bloko-button');

    blockButton.appendChild(button);
}
```

в консоле выдает ошибку:
Minified React error #423; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=423 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
и
Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=423 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
Но как решить это я понять не могу(
Манифест

```js
{
    "name": "__MSG_name__",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "default_locale": "en",
    "description": "__MSG_description__",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "32": "icons/logo-32.png",
        "64": "icons/logo-64.png",
        "128": "icons/logo-128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "all_frame": false,
            "js": ["js/content.js"],
            "css": ["css/style.css"]
        }
    ],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "storage",
        "alarms",
        "notifications",
        "downloads"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "js/background.js"
    }
}
```

Фактически когда загружается страница моя кнопка появляется буквально на мгновение и пропадает.

Подскажите что делать.

Comment: Поскольку без более корректной ссылки на источник блока нет возможности найти ваш селектор `.bloko-button-group` (я пытался) то могу лишь предположить, что возможно на вышеупомянутом сайте происходит динамическая подзагрузка и вашему скрипту не за что ухватиться. Есть и другая версия связанная с параметром манифеста — "run_at" который отвечает за стадии загрузки.

Comment: Вот что происходит при загрузке страницы
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12YsSbY2ablTw_nUTAKXiOU8wrPJo6_Wy/view?usp=sharing
В манифесте ставил: "run_at": "document_end" и  "run_at": "document_idle", результат одинаковый.

Comment: тут дело точно не в `run_at`. Пришлось даже зарегаться на ха-ха, чтобы найти вашу кнопку. Посмотрел. Там что-то явно происходит сделано криворукими за счёт javascript. Объяснить вкратце не получится. Но я бы порекомендовал вам познакомиться с `точками останова` и попробовать исследовать страницу самому на стадии загрузки. Для начала точку ставьте на `<form>`  (модификация поддерева).  А дальше, для решения поставленной задачи у вас встанет не самый простой вопрос отлова нужного вам фрагмента при помощи https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver